# unable to debug Jmeter through CLI

Tags: linux, centos, jmeter

I'm trying to run Jmeter through command line on Centos VM like so:

```
./jmeter -n -t temp_cli/sampler.jmx -l temp_cli/results.xml -j temp_cli/j.log
```

I get :

```
  INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: sampler flow 1-1 
 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: sampler flow 1-1 
DEBUG - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Ending thread sampler 1-1 
    summary =      1 in     1s =    2.0/s Avg:   434 Min:   434 Max:   434 Err:     1 (100.00%)
    Tidying up ...    @ Wed Apr 13 07:57:42 UTC 2016 (1460534262577)
    ... end of run
```

It supposed to take more than 1s so I'm pretty sure somthing went wrong. The thing is I don't get enough data about what went wrong.
I tried `tail -f jmeter.log` but I got no errors

Anyone knows how can I get more information?

Answer (score 1):

Your file results.xml will give you more details.

You can see here that you got 100% error rate so your unique sample failed.

If you are running the test in non gui mode on a different machine from where you ran the gui mode, then you most probably did not install the plugin jars.